# UTF-8 and CGI::Ajax

Tags: ajax, utf-8, cgi

I have cgi script pulling search terms from an HTML form through `CGI::Ajax`. When running `Encode::Detect::Detector` over the resulting string in my script, I get, instead of just UTF-8, a variety of encodings depending on the characters entered in the form: Greek chars turn up as `UTF-8`, umlauts as `windows-1252` and no output at all for ASCII characters. I am fairly sure the problem lies with whatever `CGI::Ajax` does to the string it passes to Perl. It uses `decodeURI()` somewhere in its code, I have tried `URI::Escape` and `Encode` in all possible permutations, but none of my attempts to normalise the different strings to a single encoding were successful. As it is, one or the other set of non-ASCII chars (either umlauts or the Greek) will always be garbled. How do I tell Ajax to keep it Unicode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: `CGI::Ajax` apparently uses Javascript’s `escape` function, which does not handle Unicode correctly. The function has been superseded by `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent`, which can be set as the default escaping functions for an `CGI::Ajax` object `$pjx` like so: `$pjx->js_encode_function('encodeURIComponent');`. Phew.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer didn't work for me, however when I changed my call from:

```
print $pjx->build_html( $cgi, \&Show_HTML);
```

to

```
print $pjx->build_html( $cgi, \&Show_HTML,  {-charset=>'UTF-8'});
```

UTF-8 characters started displaying correctly.

Source: http://search.cpan.org/~bpederse/CGI-Ajax-0.707/lib/CGI/Ajax.pm